# Measurable Functions Royden p63 Q14

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m\left(E\right) < \infty$. For $\epsilon > 0$, show that there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ such that $f$ is bounded
on $F$ and $m\left(E ∼ F\right) < \epsilon$.

Comment: I am having a problem on the bounded portion. Help on this one please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each positive integer $n$, put
$$
F_n = \{x\in E:|f(x)| \leq n\}.
$$
Then $F_1\subset F_2\subset \dots$, and $m(\bigcup F_n) = m(E)$. That is, $m(F_n) \to m(E)$ as $n\to \infty$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $N$ be such that $m(E) - m(F_N) < \epsilon$.